# Android Maven appcompat "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: android, maven, noclassdeffounderror, android-appcompat

we are writing an Android app and we use Maven for our dependency management. Our app targets Android 4.4 (API version 19) and we want to integrate the Navigation Drawer into the Action Bar. Since we need to use the support library v7 appcompat to do this, so added it to our Nexus and the dependency to our POM. Maven successfully builds the app, but when we run it, we get the following error message in LogCat:

```
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at com.foo.bar.ui.ListNavActivity.onCreate(ListNavActivity.java:33)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at com.foo.bar.ui.OrderListActivity.onCreate(OrderListActivity.java:35)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2147)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5074)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-09 10:38:00.528: E/AndroidRuntime(12277):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The relevant part of the POM is the following:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2_r4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>22.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>22.2.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>22.2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.simpligility.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        android-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [4.1.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>emma</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>21</platform>
                </sdk>
                <genDirectory>target/android/gen</genDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <assetsDirectory>${basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <androidManifestFile>${basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Edit: My co-worker tried changing the target to API 21, but it had no effect. However, he included the .aar of appcompat, he found this idea here https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer/issues/271, which fixed the NoClassDefFoundError :). It looks like stylable was contained in the .aar. The addition to the POM looks as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
            <version>22.2.0</version>
            <type>aar</type>
<!--            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
                    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
            <version>22.2.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, he is now getting a new error:

```
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204): Process: com.foo.bar.app, PID: 24204
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foo.bar.app/com.foo.bar.app.ui.activity.OrderListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at com.foo.bar.app.ui.activity.OrderListActivity.onCreate(OrderListActivity.java:76)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5539)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
07-13 15:07:22.967 E/AndroidRuntime(24204):     ... 11 more
07-13 15:07:24.302 I/AndroidRuntime(24303): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
07-13 15:07:27.677 I/AndroidRuntime(24684): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
```

I'm not at work, but my co-worker told me that this occurs when the app tries to access the action bar. It also seems like appcompat does not contain any class file of the UI-components. Do you have an idea what the problem is? Please tell me if you need any additional information or if something is unclear.

Comment: You have to target and to compile with api 21+

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :). Isn't this a problem when we want to run the app on Android 4.4?

Comment: No. Don't confuse them with the minsdk

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I will try that when I am at work next time and report back.

Comment: My co-worker tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not help. However, he found another solution which fixed the old error. But now, when running the app, there is a new exception, so I don't know if this really fixed it. Please see my edit. Any idea is very appreciated.

Comment: It is a different error. post your OrderListActivity.onCreate method, highlighting the line 76.